# Porting extensible array indexing (Ix and family) to Java

Tags: java, arrays, haskell, porting

Although I consider myself an lower-intermediate Haskeller (understand RankNTypes, but struggle with arrow "proc" notation), I am even more noobish at Java.  Nevertheless, I decided that the one thing I couldn't do without in Java was something akin to the `Ix` type class and Haskell's flexibly indexed arrays.  I set out to make my own, but I've come right smack up against my own lack of experience.  Can anyone give me any advice or pointers on this task?  Am I going about it all wrong, or do I have the right idea?  Does the Java SE 7 Platform already have something like this that I somehow missed?  Has someone else already done this?

I have the following interface simulating the `Ix` type class:

```
public interface Ix<T extends Ix<T>> {
    int indexIn(IxRange<T> range);
    boolean isIn(IxRange<T> range);
    boolean isFirstIn(IxRange<T> range);
    boolean isLastIn(IxRange<T> range);
    T nextIndexIn(IxRange<T> range);
    T prevIndexIn(IxRange<T> range);
    IxRange<T> maxRange();
}
```

I couldn't copy the original type class exactly due to lack of static methods in interfaces, as usual with Java, but I think this is a reasonable way around that (other than `maxRange()`, which just bugs me).  If anyone has any better ideas, please tell me.

Since I didn't have tuples available (I don't want to depend on [FunctionalJava](http://functionaljava.org/)), I made the following class (`Ix<T>` methods, among others, omitted).

```
public class IxRange<T extends Ix<T>> implements Ix<IxRange<T>> {
    public final T lowerBound;
    public final T upperBound;

    public IxRange(T lB,T uB) {
        lowerBound = lB;
        upperBound = uB;
    }

    public int rangeSize() {
        return upperBound.indexIn(this) - lowerBound.indexIn(this);
    }
}
```

I then have a class that begins like this:

```
public class FlexArray<I extends Ix<I>,E> extends AbstractList<E> implements Cloneable
```

This is where I am having the most trouble, primarily, but by no means exclusively, due to needing an instance first in order to call `maxRange()` (gah!).  I also have several wrapper classes for common types that implement the `Ix<T>` interface, but that's an auxiliary concern.

To sum up, I am looking for advice on how to proceed, and, if possible, how to refactor `Ix<I>` to get rid of `maxRange()` and replace it with something better.  General thoughts on the task are welcome as well, but are not the point of this question.

Comment: Don't know if this would help, but Frege (code.google.com/p/frege) could translate source code derived from Haskell98/2010 to Java. The generated code still would depend on the Frege Runtime, but maybe gives an idea how to do it. OTOH, if you don't want laziness it wouldn't help that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach would be to use "first class typeclasses" also known as the "concept pattern" you dont get inference, and it isnt exactly as clean as using an oo interface directly, but makes more sense when you need to have things like binary methods.  You can completely avoid the "curiously recurring generic pattern" (`Ix<T extends Ix<T>>`) which simplifies things, but at the expense of needing to pass the dictionaries by hand

```
public interface Ix<A>{
   public List<A> range(A start,A end);
   public int index(A start,A end,A el);
   public boolean inRange(A start,A end,A el);
   public int rangeSize(A start,A end);
}
```

To use this, you just create your "instances" like you would in Haskell

```
public class IxInteger extends Ix<Integer>{
    //use the singelton pattern 
    private static IxInteger instance = new IxInteger();
    public static IxInteger getInstance(){
       return instance;
    }
    private IxInteger(){
       //most likely doesn't need to do anything
    }
    //implement the typeclass
    public List<Integer> range(Integer start,Integer end){
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(end-start);
       for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
           list.add(i);
       }
       return list;
    }
    ...
}
```

You then just pass the dictionary in whenever you need it.

```
public Foo ixFoo<A>(args..,Ix<A> ixDict){
   // do stuff
   ...
   // and when you need the dictionary
   myList = ixDict.range(start,end);
   ...
}
```

---

Edit: One problem is that when translating code sometimes you do stupid things.  In Haskell `[a]` is used as a sort of universal interface to iterable collections.  This doesn't really work in strict languages. So, one should probably replace the use of `List<A>` in my code with an iterator.  It is best to retain the laziness in times like this.

Comment: Is it okay, then, to trample one or two of `List<E>`'s methods, as you seem to be doing?  I have always been told that's a no-no.  :/

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, since you are unlikely to have anything that could be both a `List` and a `Ix` instance